# How to replace all occurrences of a string with strings from an array

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string that contains "..." in different places.
And a string array with the same amount of words as the number of "...".

I want to replace all occurrences of "..." with the words from the string array.

```
let stringToReplace = "I want an ... that I get from the ..."
let stringArray = ["apple","shop"]

result = "I want an apple that I get from the shop"
```

I have tried this:

```
let result = stringToReplace;
for (let i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
   let inloc = stringArray[i];
   result = result.replace("...", inloc);
}
```

But that would only change the first occurrence of "...".

Comment: I tried your example and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let s = "I want an ... that I get from the ..."
let r = ["apple","shop"]

console.log(s.split('...').flatMap((e,i)=>[e,r[i]]).join(''));
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```js
//  stringToReplace = "I want an ... that I get from the ..."
//  stringArray = ["apple","shop"]

// result = "I want an apple that I get from the shop"

function replaceString(stringToReplace, stringArray) {
  var result = stringToReplace;
  for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
    result = result.replace("...", stringArray[i]);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(
  replaceString("I want an ... that I get from the ...", ["apple", "shop"])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good use case for [JS Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
let stringToReplace = "I want an ... that I get from the ..."
let stringArray = ["apple","shop"]

const PLACEHOLDER = '...'

const replaceWords = (stringWithPlaceholders, variablesArray) => {
  const finalString = stringWithPlaceholders.split(PLACEHOLDER).reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
      const variableToAdd = variablesArray[i]
      const newStringSection = variableToAdd ? `${acc}${curr}${variableToAdd}` : `${acc}${curr}`
      
      return newStringSection
    }, '')

  return finalString
}

console.log(replaceWords(stringToReplace, stringArray))

// => 'I want an apple that I get from the shop'
```

You might want to add in some default replacement in the case that you don't have the right amount of elements in your variables array, but this should help as a starting point.